# Dynamic out-of-component translation with t macro in Lingui

Tags: reactjs, macros, internationalization, linguijs

I'm trying to translate something like this `"User {id} payments"` to both English and Hungarian. How can I do it with the t macro with my current setup?

```
title: (id, i18n) => t(i18n)`userPayments`,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in my case was:

```
18n._({
    "userPayments",
    message: "User {id} payments",
    values,
});
```

Where `values` is: `{ id: payment.id }`.

Answer (score 0):

The `t` macro does not support variables. You should try using `<Trans />` which supports variables and can be helpful in your case.

Here is an example code

```js
// strings.json
"user_id": "User {{id}} payments"
```

```js
const id = "123"
<Trans i18nKey={"user_id"} values={{id}} />

// output
"User 123 payments"
```

There are more options here depending on your setup, check https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component

Comment: I need to translate the title of the web page. Is that possible with <Trans />?

Comment: Won't be possible, in the title. For your use-case then, you would have to try with  
 
```javascript
useEffect(() => {
    document.title = t('app_title', { /* your variables here */ });
  }, [t])
```

Or use `react-helmet`. But keep in mind the react-helmet approach does not use `<Trans />`

Comment: I never tried to translate the title with https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet, so `useEffect` might be the way to go, it will help the use case where you need interpolate (to add a variable in your title)

Comment: Hey! I achieved my desired outcome with
`i18n._({
    id,
    message: fallback,
    values,
    comment,
  });`

Comment: Thank you for following up, this is useful info for me as well.